# ¿Cómo filtrar texto en URL?

Tags: php

Cómo puedo reemplazar caracteres especiales mediante PHP o `.htaccess`, caracteres como por ejemplo `áàäæāâãą` para poder pasarlo por una url sin que me de un error, ya que mi `.htaccess` lo tengo configurado para que solo acepte caracteres alfanuméricos, - y _.

Me gustaría poder remplazarlos adecuadamente, por ejemplo `É` a `E`, o de `é` a `e`, y así sucesivamente.

Mi htaccess es este:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]+)$ /?text=$1 [NC,L]
```

Como pueden ver creo una url amigable, para no dar a conocer los distintos querys y solo aceptan caracteres alfanuméricos, - y _ mas no caracteres especiales.

Comment: ¿Podrías decirnos si las URLs (los enlaces) la generas tú u otra aplicación? ¿Quieres filtrar en origen o en destino? ¿Podrías incluir tu `.htaccess` por si te podemos ayudar a mejorarlo para aceptar cualquier carácter?

Comment: Listo ya añadí mi código fe htaccess, espero puedas ayudarme, y gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edición:**

Tras debatir en el chat cuál era el problema en el uso de tildes, eñes, etc, llegamos a la conclusión que era una limitación de una llamada a un API externo, por lo que esta solución podría también valer:

Usar un `.htaccess` más relajado (para evitar errores "404 not found" en URLs amigables que no concuerdan con los caracteres permitidos):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?text=$1
```

Tras ello obtenemos en `$_GET['text']` el contenido de la URL decodificado (en `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` estaría codificado en URL y, además, con la barra `/` inicial), por lo que podemos eliminar todos los caracteres que no están permitidos en el API llamado:

```
<?php
/* Eliminamos todo lo que no sean letras, números, espacios y guiones */
$consulta = mb_eregi_replace('[^a-z0-9áéíóúñ_\- ]', '', $_GET['text']);
```

Hay que hacer uso de [`mb_eregi_replace`](http://php.net/mb_eregi_replace) y no [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace) para que interprete correctamente los caracteres multibyte.

---

**Respuesta original:**

Si todo tu entorno trabaja en UTF-8 (las cabeceras que devuelve tu servidor, el juego de caracteres que usa tu HTML, etc) entonces podrías transliterar tu cadena de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
/* ¡¡OJO!! C.UTF-8 no funciona correctamente con todos los caracteres */
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8', 'en_US.utf8', 'C.UTF-8') === false) {
  die('No se pudo seleccionar localismo, use "locale -a" para obtener listado disponible');
}
$titulo = '¿Estará dando caña? ¡Viva! ¡ÁNIMO!';
function url_amigable($texto) {
    /* Transliteramos caracteres UTF-8 a ASCII */
    $texto = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $texto);
    /* Eliminamos cualquier carácter no deseado */
    $texto = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9_\- ]/i', '', $texto);
    /* Convertimos los espacios en _ para evitar el %20 */
    return str_replace(' ', '_', $texto);
}
/* El uso de rawurlencode es opcional sólo en este caso teniendo en cuenta el
  conjunto de caracteres filtrado, pero es aconsejable usarlo siempre */
$url = 'http://www.prueba.com/articulo/' .
    rawurlencode(url_amigable($titulo));
echo $url;
```

El resultado será: *http://www.prueba.com/articulo/Estara_dando_cana_Viva_ANIMO*

Para saber qué localizaciones están instaladas en tu servidor y disponibles para [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) usa `locale -a` en la consola. Si te faltan las localizaciones en castellano podrías instalarlas con un `sudo apt-get install language-pack-es`.

Es necesario que tengas instalado soporte para [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv), y que esté bien configuradas las locales para que se transliteren correctamente en ASCII.

Si en algún momento permites un carácter que pudiera formar parte de una URL (como `/`, `?`, `&`, `%`, etc) debes usar [`rawurlencode`](http://php.net/rawurlencode) para convertirlos en sus correspondencias hexadecimales precedidas de `%`.

Por otro lado, se podrían convertir todos los caracteres UTF-8 a ASCII en `.htaccess`, pero tendrías que hacerlo carácter a carácter de la siguiente manera:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xa1(.*) $1a$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xa9(.*) $1e$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\xad(.*) $1i$2 [R,L]
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\x81(.*) $1A$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\x89(.*) $1E$2 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\xc3\x8d(.*) $1I$2 [R,L]
...
```

Puedes consultar el código hexadecimal de cualquier carácter en una tabla UTF-8 buscando por "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE", por poner un ejemplo.

Esta solución es compleja y podría impactar negativamente en rendimiento general de tu servidor, por lo que te recomiendo hacer la conversión en origen (cuando generas la URL) o en destino (cuando vas a usar los datos de la URL).

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63906/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-animationsnow).